# ERROR [TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined], y no sé que hacer

Tags: discord.js, bot

El 2020-2021 hice un bot de Discord de música, el problema es que no me acuerdo como lo hice, ya que lo hice con un amigo y ahora supongo que tengo que actualizar un poco el código. En fin, ahora me da el error: "[TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined]" y "TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined"
at Object.execute (.../Music/play.js:115:36)" en la consola y en el Discord, cuando pongo "!play (algo aleatorio o un link cualquiera)". Dejo aquí el código:

```
const { play } = require("../include/play");
const { Client, Collection, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { attentionembed } = require("../util/attentionembed");
const YouTube = require("youtube-sr").default;
const { search } = require("youtube-sr");

module.exports = {
  name: "play",
  aliases: ["p"],
  description: "Plays song from YouTube/Stream",
  cooldown: 0.1,
  edesc: `Type this command to play some music.\nUsage: ${PREFIX}play <TITLE | URL>`,

  /.../
    //define some url patterns
    const search = args.join(" ");
    const videoPattern = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/gi;
    const urlValid = videoPattern.test(args[0]);

    //define Queue Construct
    const queueConstruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      channel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      loop: false,
      volume: 100,
      filters: [],
      realseek: 0,
      playing: true
    };
    //get song infos to null
    let songInfo = null;
    let song = null;
    //try catch for errors
    try {
      //If something is playing
      if (serverQueue) {
        //if its an url
        if (urlValid) { //send searching link
          message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setColor("#F0EAD6")
            .setDescription(`**:notes: Searching  [\`LINK\`](${args.join(" ")})**`))
            console.log (`Command play used`)
        //if not
        }
        else { //send searching TITLE
          message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setColor("#F0EAD6")
            .setDescription(`**:notes: Searching  \`${args.join(" ")}\`**`))
            console.log (`Command play used`)
        }
      } else {
        //If nothing is playing join the channel
        queueConstruct.connection = await channel.join();
        //send join message
        message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setColor("#F0EAD6")
          .setDescription(`** Joined \`${channel.name}\`  bound \`#${message.channel.name}\`**`)
          .setFooter(`By: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`))
        //if its an url
        if (urlValid) { //send searching link
          message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setColor("#F0EAD6")
            .setDescription(`**:notes: Searching  [\`LINK\`](${args.join(" ")})**`))
            console.log (`Command play used`)
          //if not 
        }
        else { //send searching TITLE
          message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setColor("#F0EAD6")
            .setDescription(`**:notes: Searching  \`${args.join(" ")}\`**`))
            console.log (`Command play used`)
        }
        //Set selfdeaf and serverdeaf true
        queueConstruct.connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
        queueConstruct.connection.voice.setDeaf(true);
      }
    }
    catch {
    }
    //if its a valid youtube link
      if (urlValid) {
        try {
          songInfo = await YouTube.search(search) ;
          song = {
            title: songInfo.title,
            url: songInfo.url,
            thumbnail: songInfo.thumbnail,
            duration: songInfo.durationFormatted,
         };
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.statusCode === 403) return attentionembed(message, "Max. uses of api Key, please refresh!");
          console.error(error);
          return attentionembed(message, error.message);
        }
      } 
    //else try to find the song via ytsr (esto actualmente lo cambié a YouTube)
    else {
      try {
       //get the result 
        songInfo = await YouTube.search(search) ;
        song = {
          title: songInfo.title,
          url: songInfo.url,
          thumbnail: songInfo.thumbnail,
          duration: songInfo.durationFormatted,
       };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return attentionembed(message, error);        
      }                                                               
    }

      serverQueue.songs.push(song);
      //the new song embed
      const newsong = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(":notes:" + song.title)
        .setColor("#F0EAD6")
        .setThumbnail(thumb)
        .setURL(song.url)
        .setDescription(`\`\`\`Has been added to the Queue.\`\`\``)
        .addField("Estimated time until playing:", `\`${estimatedtime}\``, true)
        .addField("Position in queue", `**\`${serverQueue.songs.length - 1}\`**`, true)
        .setFooter(`Requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`, message.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
      //send the Embed into the Queue Channel
        return serverQueue.textChannel
        .send(newsong)
        .catch(console.error);
      
    }
    //push the song list by 1 to add it to the queu
    queueConstruct.songs.push(song);
    //set the queue
    message.client.queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);
    //playing with catching errors
    try {
    
      //try to play the song
      play(queueConstruct.songs[0], message, client);
    } catch (error) {
      //if an error comes log
      console.error(error);
      //delete the Queue
      message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      //leave the channel
      await channel.leave();
      //sent an error message
      return attentionembed(message, `Could not join the channel: ${error}`); 
    }
  }
};
```

El error creo que debe ser el "YouTube.search(search)", ya que antes, el módulo era ytsr no YouTube, y lo cambié, pero sigue sin funcionar, y no se que hacer para hacerlo funcionar.
Intenté agregar todo lo posible, intenté cambiar variables, intenté buscar en internet soluciones, y nada. A ver si aquí tengo suerte ‍♀️